# Can't see bing chat icon in Microsoft Edge Web Browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

I understand that as of 2023, Microsoft with their Edge web browser has now integrated an AI LLM known as "Bing chat".  I'd like to access it.

I looked at this link here that speaks of removing the bing AI icon, (though I don't want to remove it)

https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/bing/you-can-now-remove-the-bing-icon-from-microsoft-edge-no-registry-edit-required

It shows what it looks like

[image]

But my edge browser looks like this

[image]

As you can see there's no blue "bing chat / bing AI" icon there in my installation of Microsoft Edge.

This article https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/bing/how-to-get-started-with-bing-chat-on-microsoft-edge   says that you must be signed into your Microsoft account.  Well, I normally use Google's Chrome browser but i'm aware that Google have a concept of a "Google account", and if I go to google.com or gmail.com and log in then i'm signed into my google account and signed into any google service whether gmail or google docs or whatever.  I don't know to what extent that does or doesn't parallel with Microsoft's concept of a microsoft account. I do have an address @outlook.com which I guess counts as a microsoft account.

I tried going to bing.com (bing being Microsoft's search engine that has been around since 2009 which I know is nothing to do with Bing chat). And I clicked signed in and managed to sign in using my outlook.com address.

And it then shows a chat link within the bing webpage.

[image]

And I notice that in chrome that chat link shows in bing.com even when not logged into bing.com

[image]

But I don't get a Bing icon in the Edge browser itself, so i'm not seeing Bing integrated with Edge.

I figured it looks a bit like not just an icon but an icon that is part of a side bar.

So I searched on bing search engine, about showing the sidebar

[image]

But there is nothing about showing a side bar

[image]

And doing ctrl-shift-/ isn't toggling showing sidebar / not, it's not doing anything. I just see no side bar. (let alone the bing icon i'm looking for!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Settings menu has many things different than that what Edge settings now has, I think your Edge is for some reason outdated (and not the most recent, v114.

Go in settings to the **About Microsoft Edge** page and check your version, and update if it's not updated.

Comment: looks like it was related to that. I went to edge's "about", it showed 92, but said updating, and is now 114 and shows a side bar now with the bing icon. So maybe the windows installation is dated to 2021, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history , v92 of edge is around 2021, learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/… and windows 10 comes bundled with Edge, and is an old Edge by default.